# How to fix Failed to clone git repository at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack.git during cf push

Tags: swisscomdev

When I try to do a cf push using nginx build pack I get

`Failed to clone git repository at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack.git`

I am trying to do a deploy my react application using cf push command and a manifest file.

This is my manifest file:

`applications:
  - name: myapp
    memory: 64M
    path: ./build/
    buildpacks:
      - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack.git`

I expect to be able to deploy an app with the nginx-buildpack. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

When I try to reference buildpack by name: **nginx_buildpack**, I get:

```
**ERROR** Could not install nginx: Get https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/nginx/nginx-1.15.8-linux-x64-cflinuxfs2-a17501d0.tgz: read tcp 11.255.129.85:58762->194.209.222.197:443: read: connection reset by peer
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 14
```

Comment: You should look at your proxy configuration ! https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to use custom buildpacks depends on the cloudfoundry platform configuration, you need to contact the admin/support of your CF environment.